# Python NameError in case of string in input

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having a problem trying to enforce my python code in order to avoid that a number out of a specific range can be provided in input.

I created a list of process to monitor and `subselect` function is to check the input validity. Accepted values should be from `1 to 9`

My design works well for number but if by mistake another type is given I get `NameErr`

```
def subselect():
    while True:
        choise = input("Please select a Subsystem to monitor: ")
        print(type(choise))
        print(choise)
        if int(choise) <= 0 or choise >= 10:
           print("Selection invalid")
        else:
           return choise


if __name__== "__main__":
    subsystem = ["","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"]
    while True:
        print("1  - a")
        print("2  - b")
        print("3  - c")
        print("4  - d")
        print("5  - e")
        print("6  - f")
        print("7  - g")
        print("8  - h")
        print("9  - i")
    select = subselect()
```

Executing the script I get NameError for provided input in case it's not numeric.

> ```
> 1  - a
> 2  - b
> 3  - c
> 4  - d
> 5  - e
> 6  - f
> 7  - g
> 8  - h
> 9  - i
> Please select a Subsystem to monitor: 20
> <type 'int'>
> 20
> Selection invalid
> Please select a Subsystem to monitor: fff
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "./MyScript.py", line 102, in <module>
>     select = subselect()
>   File "./MyScript.py", line 72, in subselect
>     choise = input("Please select a Subsystem to monitor: ")
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
> **NameError: name 'fff' is not defined**
> ```

I also tried to use int but same result
choise = int(input("Please select a Subsystem to monitor: "))

Comment: Sounds like you're using python 2 and need to use `raw_input`

Comment: kindly add relevant version tag of language too while asking question. like you can use both tag `python` because it's parent tag and `python-2.x` or `python-3.x` suitable to your question

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 2, you need to use `raw_input` like this:

```
choise = raw_input("Please select a Subsystem to monitor: ")
```

Because in python2.x, `input` returns raw code instead of a string. In python3.x however, you would need something like this to get the raw code:

```
exec('a='+input('enter some raw code'))
```

Or if you just want a variable:

```
a=eval(input('enter a variable (like this: var) that has been previously assigned, or like this: 'some text', 5, [1, 2, 3]'))
```

Comment: I'm using Python 2.6.6. I tried already your suggestion but I get ValueError instead

Comment: What's your specific error? @AntonioNovi

Comment: It works. Next error was because I put choise = int(choise) . Thanks a lot

Comment: If it works, mark it as accepted. It gives you 2 rep and the answerer 15 rep. You can do this by pressing the green tick next to the question @AntonioNovi. If you have a new question, post it as such.